# How to customize array order for select

Tags: php, mysql, bug-tracking

Im not PHP developer (Rails only) but i have task in PHP code (thebuggenie-app) which tell me that i have to change order of displaying options for select. Problem maybe is simple but for me its not that very easy.

What I have seen in php project i have something like this to select (after mini research):

```
<optgroup label="<?php echo __('Globally available roles'); ?>">
 <?php foreach ($global_roles as $role): ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $role->getId(); ?>">
  <?php echo $role>getName(); ?></option>
 <?php endforeach ;?>
</optgroup>
```

and (probably) global_roles is a array which will be iterated. In Rails its easy to make custom order but it this case i have no idea. If you need any information just let me know.

in action class i found: `$this->global_roles = TBGRole::getAll();`

and this one redirect my mind to:

```
/**
* Returns all project roles available
* 
* @return array 
*/      
public static function getAll()
 {
    return TBGListTypesTable::getTable()->getAllByItemTypeAndItemdata(self::ROLE, null);
 }
```

[image]

For now i have developer as a first option (default) and i need to have Tester as a 1st (default) option

Every solution will be right for me if code will work :)

Update 1)

```
public function getAllByItemTypeAndItemdata($itemtype, $itemdata)
 {
   $this->_populateItemCache();
   $items = (array_key_exists($itemtype, self::$_item_cache)) ? self::$_item_cache[$itemtype] : array();
   foreach ($items as $id => $item)
     {
       if ($item->getItemdata() != $itemdata) unset($items[$id]);
     }

     return $items;
 }
```

Comment: it's more sql question. Could you provide  `getAllByItemTypeAndItemdata()` code?

Comment: getAllByItemTypeAndItemdata() in update 1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use usort().
This function sort, using a second function, which you create and passes parameter.
Ex :

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{   
    if ($a == $b) {
    return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$chave: $valor\n";
}
?>
```